# Transofrmations on dom elements

Tags: html, dom

At first I was really excited about HTML5's canvas element. But It will not work for my idea now that i understand what it is intended for.

Basically I want to display an unordered list in 3rd dimention by perfroming a slight rotation on it about the y-axis. Nothing "basic" about that. Is there any jquery plugin that can help me to create this illusion? 
If not, I may have to attempt to create one myself. see below.

```
 <div id="angleit" class="padding">
     <ul>
         <li>item 1</li>
         <li>item 2</li>
         <li>item 3</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create it myself.

Even worse, I already did: http://annejan.com/html5/demo/jinx.js

NOTE THE EXAMPLE IS CANVAS BUT THE MATH SHOULD WORK WITH OTHER ELEMENTS ALSO.

The following code allows for rotation in 2 angles, it's trivial to add a third angle.

For your (exact) question it could even be simplified!

```
this.rotateXY = function(angleX, angleY) {
  // might do with some more hard coding ;)
  var xy, xz, yz;

  sinRY = Math.sin(angleX * TO_RADIANS);
  cosRY = Math.cos(angleX * TO_RADIANS);
  sinRX = Math.sin(angleY * TO_RADIANS);
  cosRX = Math.cos(angleY * TO_RADIANS);

  xy = (cosRX*this.y)-(sinRX*this.z);
  xz = (sinRX*this.y)+(cosRX*this.z);
  yz = (cosRY*xz)-(sinRY*this.x);
  this.x = (sinRY*xz)+(cosRY*this.x);
  this.y = xy;
  this.z = yz;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to rotate a ul inside a div about 30 degrees or so. I think only the x and z coordinates alone will change. Do I need a canvas to have a z axis or can i simply manipulate the dom with jquery as you have shown?

Comment: The code for rendering the 3D in a 2D plane is in the link as-well.

Answer (score 1):

CSS 3D is only supported by some of webkit browsers. The other browsers can only emulate 3D behavior by using 2D transforms (scale and skew).

For this purpose [jQuery 2D Transformation Plugin](https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/) is cross browser IE6+ solution.

If you want CSS 3D transforms, then you may use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to check if they are supported, otherwise fall back to 2D emulation using jQuery 2D Transformation Plugin.

Comment: I think that's definitely easier than my route below ;)

Comment: @the JinX: I'm just not sure about canvas being used to do the transformations on dom elements, or maybe I just don't understand the problem. I would like to know why my answer is unacceptable by the questioner.